# CakePHP 3 - Make a copy of bin/cake executable?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I wonder if there is any way I could make a copy of `bin/cake` and name it `bin/cake.live` to run in production?

When I did that, this error comes up:

> Exception: Shell class for "Cake.Live" could not be found. in
>   [/home/bravier/builderslink-invoice.staging2.abweb.com.au/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/ShellDispatcher.php, line 324]

Comment: Why would you even want to do this? You shouldn't really be changing anything in `bin/cake`.

Comment: I also dont follow. Why is `chmod +x bin/cake` not working?

Comment: On production server, we have a different PHP version used by the site (wrapped by cPanel's FPM), so we have to specify the right PHP bin path for `bin/cake` to execute.